# list of objects to be serialized as json, how do I define a key name at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, list, serialization

Here is an example of the output that is expected (out of my control unfortunately):

```
{
    "the_date":"2013-10-19,"
    "users":
        {
            "john doe":
                {
                    "telephone":"123-456-7890",
                    "email":"jodoe@server.com"
                }
        },
        {
            "jane doe":
                {
                    "telephone":"123-456-7891",
                    "email":"jadoe@server.com"
                }
        }
}
```

I am creating my data in vb.net using Lists of objects, and Serializing it like so:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization



Public Class the_data

    Property the_date As String
    Property users As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of jsuser_data)))

    Public Sub New()

        the_date = "2013-10-19"

        Dim dtUserNames As New DataTable 'hardcoded list for testing only
        dtUserNames.Columns.Add("fldUserId", GetType(Integer))
        dtUserNames.Columns.Add("fldUserName", GetType(String))

        dtUserNames.Rows.Add(100, "john doe")
        dtUserNames.Rows.Add(101, "jane doe")

        Using reader As New DataTableReader(New DataTable() {dtUserNames})
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While (reader.Read())
                    Dim test As New List(Of jsuser_data)
                    test.Add(New jsuser_data(reader("fldUserId")))
                    users.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of jsuser_data))(reader("fldUserName").ToString, test)) 'THIS IS THE LINE OF NOTE
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub


End Class


Public Class jsuser_data
    Property telephone As String
    Property email As String

    Public Sub New(theUserId As String)

        Dim dtUserData As New DataTable 'hardcoded list for testing only, yes I know it will return the same data for both, I am just simulating my sproc call
        dtUserData.Columns.Add("fldUserId", GetType(Integer))
        dtUserData.Columns.Add("fldTelephone", GetType(String))
        dtUserData.Columns.Add("fldEmail", GetType(String))

        dtUserData.Rows.Add(100, "123-456-7890", "jdoe@server.com")

        Using reader As New DataTableReader(New DataTable() {dtUserData})
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While (reader.Read())
                    telephone = reader("fldTelephone")
                    email = reader("fldEmail")
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class

Partial Class Default3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim jsonString As String
        Dim test As New the_data()

        jsonString = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(test)
        Response.Write(jsonString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

After trying a lot of different ways, that is as close as I have gotten. However, it is outputting the words "key" and "value" as in the following:

```
{
    "the_date":"2013-10-19",
    "users":[
        {"Key":"john doe",
        "Value":[
            {"telephone":"123-456-7890","email":"jdoe@server.com"}
            ]
        },
        {"Key":"jane doe",
        "Value":[
            {"telephone":"123-456-7890","email":"jdoe@server.com"}
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Do I need to write a custom JSON serializer or is there something I am missing? I tried to be as thorough in my question as possible and I've utterly confused myself in all my attempts & searching, so please let me know if more data is needed to answer.
Thanks!

EDIT:
Based on nicolas-straub-valdivieso's suggestion, I have changed the "the_data" object to:

```
Public Class the_data

    Property the_date As String
    'Property users As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of jsuser_data)))
    Property users As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of jsuser_data))

    Public Sub New()

        the_date = "2013-10-19"

        Dim dtUserNames As New DataTable 'hardcoded list for testing only
        dtUserNames.Columns.Add("fldUserId", GetType(Integer))
        dtUserNames.Columns.Add("fldUserName", GetType(String))

        dtUserNames.Rows.Add(100, "john doe")
        dtUserNames.Rows.Add(101, "jane doe")

        Using reader As New DataTableReader(New DataTable() {dtUserNames})
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While (reader.Read())
                    Dim test As New List(Of jsuser_data)
                    test.Add(New jsuser_data(reader("fldUserId")))
                    users.Add(reader("fldUserName").ToString, test) 'THIS IS THE LINE OF NOTE
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub


End Class
```

and now my output is:

```
{
    "the_date":"2013-10-19",
    "users":
        {
            "john doe":[
                {"telephone":"123-456-7890",
                "email":"jdoe@server.com"}
            ],
            "jane doe":[
                {"telephone":"123-456-7890",
                "email":"jdoe@server.com"}
            ]
        }
}
```

The only difference between that and the example output I was given is the [] around the user data, and that might be OK.

Comment: perhaps a dictionary would do the trick? (i.e. replace keyvaluepair with dictionary<string, List<juser_data>>)

Comment: also, check out JSON.net - http://james.newtonking.com/json It's much more advanced than MS's implementation and allows custom serialization options and pre/post serialization hooks

Comment: Looks like dictionary solves it! I changed the property to "Property users As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of jsuser_data))" and the line inside the loop to "users.Add(reader("fldUserName").ToString, test) " and it appears to be very close, the only complaint is I am getting square brackets, but that might/should be acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: those square brackets are mandatory. In fact, the expected output you post would throw a parse error (you need to wrap the list in either {} or [])

Answer (score 0):

Change the KeyValuePair to a Dictionary (added answer so you can mark the question as solved). the square brackets are necesarry so JSON can recognize the construct as an array (in fact, the format you're being asked for would throw a parse error, since you have to surround you're does with either {} (object) or [] (array).

Edit: I hadn't seen your updated code... if you change the prop from `Dictionary(of string,List(of jsuser_data))` to `Dictionary(of string,jsuser_data)` the extra braces will go away.